# Proving that there is no surjection from $A$ to $2^A$ for any infinite set $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If set $A$ is finite, then $|A|<|2^A|=|p(A)|$, and so there is no surjection from set $A$ to its powerset. Show that this is still true if $A$ is infinite.
>
> Hint: Remember Russell’s paradox and consider $\{x \in A\mid x \notin f(x)\}$ where $f$ is such surjection.

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to start. Thanks!

Comment: The hint is pretty good; you'll be off to a good start if you assume a surjection $f : A \to P(A)$ exists, and you'll want to consider the given set. How well do you know Russell's paradox?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/

Comment: I actually don't understand Russell's paradox. That's why I'm so confused. I've read about it but I didn't get it. Sorry.

Comment: A proof of your question is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem#Proof)

Comment: Notice that $\{x \in A\mid x \notin f(x)\}$ is in the power set of $A$, so if $f$ is surjective there must be an element of $A$ that maps to it.